# How do I run a kestrel asp.net app within a wpf application instance

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core

I have a website built in asp.net core 2.2 and I want to be able to use a wpf application to start and manage the service runtime using the standard asp.net core startup routine via using a Process.Start with the console redirected into logging. My plan is to allow the user to configure the port, etc from within the wpf user interface and then launch the process using that information and allow for some monitoring of the console output.

Is it a negative experience for the user to run a windowless process.startinfo used that way given they understand it's deploying a web service? (beyond having to wait for the spinup time of kestrel)

Comment: Have you considered this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: Can any of you post an answer as how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I embedded a .net core Blazor application in a WPF application by launching the compiled .net core executable with `Process.Start`. The WPF app opens a websocket on localhost which the .net core app conncets to for inter-process communication.